# Powershell ForEach, ignore blanks in csv

Tags: powershell, for-loop, foreach, foreach-object

Powershell is a completely foreign language to me, but I am trying to do this project where I am going through a list of Tickers in a csv file and if the tickers exist, I want to extract those and add them to my list. However, if the ticker is blank, I want the code to get the sedol. Can you help fix this line?

```
$pos = $text | Select-Object -Skip $i -First ($end-$i) | ConvertFrom-Csv;
$pos | ForEach-Object {if ($_.Ticker.Substring(1) -ne $null) {$_.Ticker = $_.Ticker.Substring(1)} else {
            {$_.Ticker = $_.SEDOL.Substring(1)}
        }}
```

Here is what the $pos object looks like:

[image]

Comment: Why are you calling `Substring(1)` - does the first character of the ticker string contain something that needs to be removed? Perhaps you can show us what `$text` looks like?

Comment: How did you read the csv file? `Get-Content` or `Import-Csv`? please open the file in notepad, copy the first 3 or 4 lines and paste that in your post as **formatted** text

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - from the screenshot it looks like there’s a leading ```’``` in the TICKER and SEDOL properties…

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yes, there is a " ' " in the beg of each string

Comment: @Theo see below copy+paste from notepad

CUSIP,TICKER,SEDOL
'912796YH6,,'BQ6C0P6
'ADI1BXDD4,'JYM3
'ADI1T8PB1,'ECM3
'ADI1VV5H6,'MFSM3
'ADI24DQS7,'NQM3

Comment: @Theo I am using ConvertFrom-Csv

Comment: No, don't put that in a comment. [Edit] your post and paste it there. Btw.. are you really still using PowerShell version 2.0 ? If not, then please remove that tag.

Comment: @Theo got the solution from chatGPT. removed the incorrect tag. thanks!